# Transform pandas data frame with column names and index values

Tags: python, pandas

I need to transform a data frame with a function that takes three inputs. In this case, I want to pass each value stored in the data frame, the name of the column where it is located and the row index.

For example, if my original data frame looks like this:

```
          col_0     col_1  ...     col_n
row_0  value_00  value_01  ...  value_0n
row_1  value_10  value_11  ...  value_1n
row_2  value_20  value_21  ...  value_2n
...         ...       ...  ...       ...
row_m  value_m0  value_m1  ...  value_mn
```

And the function is defined as something like:

```
def func(row_index, col_name, value):
    # Some code
```

My final data frame should look like this:

```
                              col_0                         col_1  ...                         col_n
row_0  func(row_0, col_0, value_00)  func(row_0, col_1, value_01)  ...  func(row_0, col_n, value_0n)
row_1  func(row_1, col_0, value_10)  func(row_1, col_1, value_11)  ...  func(row_1, col_n, value_1n)
row_2  func(row_2, col_0, value_20)  func(row_2, col_1, value_21)  ...  func(row_2, col_n, value_2n)
...                             ...                           ...  ...                           ...
row_m  func(row_m, col_0, value_m0)  func(row_m, col_1, value_m1)  ...  func(row_m, col_n, value_mn)
```

So far I have managed to accomplish this by iterating through rows and building a new data frame or doing some very clunky use of the apply methods like:

```
df = df.apply(lambda col: pd.DataFrame(col).apply(lambda row: func(row.name, col.name, row[col.name]), axis=1))
```

which is far from being readable. I was wondering if there was an elegant, short and easy to read way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use numpy indexing in list comprehension for improve performance:

```
#convert indices, columns and DataFrame to numpy array
arr = df.to_numpy()
idx = df.index.to_numpy()
cols = df.columns.to_numpy()

#get number of index and columns
noi, noc = arr.shape

loop and select values by indexing
out = pd.DataFrame([[func(idx[i], cols[c], arr[i, c]) for c in np.arange(noc)]
                     for i in np.arange(noi)], 
                     index=df.index,
                     columns=df.columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a nested list comprehension will be more efficient than a nested apply:

```
from itertools import product

def func(row_index, col_name, value):
    return f'func({row_index}, {col_name}, {value})'

out = pd.DataFrame([[func(i, c, df.at[i, c]) for c in df.columns]
                    for i in df.index],
                   index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

Output:

```
                              col_0                         col_1                         col_n
row_0  func(row_0, col_0, value_00)  func(row_0, col_1, value_01)  func(row_0, col_n, value_0n)
row_1  func(row_1, col_0, value_10)  func(row_1, col_1, value_11)  func(row_1, col_n, value_1n)
row_2  func(row_2, col_0, value_20)  func(row_2, col_1, value_21)  func(row_2, col_n, value_2n)
row_m  func(row_m, col_0, value_m0)  func(row_m, col_1, value_m1)  func(row_m, col_n, value_mn)
```

Comparison of timing on the example:

```
# list comprehension
132 µs ± 5.53 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

# nested apply
1.01 ms ± 41.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using applymap :

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample function
def func(row_index, col_name, value):
    return f"func({row_index}, {col_name}, {value})"

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'col_0': ['value_00', 'value_10', 'value_20'],
    'col_1': ['value_01', 'value_11', 'value_21'],
    'col_n': ['value_0n', 'value_1n', 'value_2n']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['row_0', 'row_1', 'row_2'])

# Applying the function to each element
result_df = df.applymap(lambda value: func(df.index[df.index.get_loc(value.name)], value.name, value))

print(result_df)
```

Comment: Using `get_loc` will have quadratic behavior, also `value.name` shouldn't work as this refers to the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient for large datasets with complex transformations.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'col_0': [1, 2, 3], 'col_1': [4, 5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)


def func(row_index, col_name, value):
    aa =  f'func({row_index}, {col_name}, {value})'
    return aa


values = df.values
row_indices = df.index.to_numpy()[:,None]
"""
print('row_indices : ',row_indices)

row_indices :  [[0]
 [1]
 [2]]
"""
col_names  = df.columns.to_numpy()
"""print('col_names : ',col_names)
col_names :  ['col_0' 'col_1']
"""
transformed_values = np.vectorize(func)(row_indices,col_names,df.values)
"""
print(transformed_values)
[['func(0, col_0, 1)' 'func(0, col_1, 4)']
 ['func(1, col_0, 2)' 'func(1, col_1, 5)']
 ['func(2, col_0, 3)' 'func(2, col_1, 6)']]

"""

transformed_df = pd.DataFrame(transformed_values,columns=df.columns,index = df.index)
 
"""
print(transformed_df)
              col_0              col_1
0  func(0, col_0, 1)  func(0, col_1, 4)
1  func(1, col_0, 2)  func(1, col_1, 5)
2  func(2, col_0, 3)  func(2, col_1, 6)

"""
```